# streamreader encoding not working on remote machine

Tags: c#, encoding

I have an email body that I read from a file. I had encoding issues which I have fixed in the past. I tried and verfied this works properly on my computer. WHen I start the app on the remote server and let it run it runs as if it isn't using UTF8.

```
using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\EmailTemplates\\Spanish.html", Encoding.UTF8);              
body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
var encodingused = sr.CurrentEncoding;
```

I have confirmed that the CurrentEncoding remotely and localy are both UTF8 using the remote debugger. I am using .net core 3.1

> Email body from remote machine: �Gracias por elegir
>
> Email body from Local Dev: ¡Gracias por elegir

Comment: Also TO add it works properly locally even when I don't add an encoding at all

Comment: The auto-detection feature only works when a text file contains byte order marks (BOM). If a local encoding is used, there's no BOM, the StreamReader will use UTF-8 or the encoding you have specified. Clearly, the encoding is not UTF-8 here. Try code page `1252` or `"ISO-8859-1"` (e.g., `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` or `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`).

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out the issue,the problem was not the code. The problem was I was using PowerShell to edit the file and upload it to the environment as part of automated deployment using Octopus Deploy. Editing the file in PS change the file to a different format (ANSI). to file the problem when I use the PS command Set content I needed to specify UFT8  `Set-Content -Path $file -Encoding UTF8`